# Ionic 4 - include a component based on property value

Tags: ionic-framework, components, conditional-statements

How can I include a component in a loop, based on a property value.
Something like:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
    ?if item.type == 1? <item1 [data]="item"></item1>
    ?if item.type == 2? <item2 [data]="item"></item1>
</ion-item>
```

I would like to avoid:

```
<item1 *ngIf="item.type == 1" [data]="item"></item1>
<item2 *ngIf="item.type == 2" [data]="item"></item2>
```

If it is possible at all.

Comment: what if you use ngif?

Comment: Yes, it works with ngIf, but I am not sure if it is the right solution.

Comment: ngif does not add items to dom, unlike hidden. It seems a right solution to me.

Comment: Thank you. I will use ngIf.